Still waiting for data on topic imu/data_raw
We are currently using the realsense d4385i cameras together with rtabmap to retrieve the visual odometry. We have followed the instruction mention in rtabmap examples and used this launch file to initiate the pipeline. It worked and have been working till last week, where we began to get the following issue
[imu_filter_madgwick_node-5] [WARN] [1722261630.037924833] [imu_filter_madgwick]: Still waiting for data on topic imu/data_raw...[stereo_odometry-3] [WARN] [1722261632.375946187] [stereo_odometry]: stereo_odometry: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. Parameter "approx_sync" is false, which means that input topics should have all the exact timestamp for the callback to be called. [stereo_odometry-3] stereo_odometry subscribed to (exact sync): 
We have tried to update the whole system but nothing works. We do get the IMU data from the cameras, but somehow imu_madgwick_filter doesn't get the IMU/data_raw.
We are currently using Humble running on a Ubuntu 22.04 PC. Hope you guys can help. Thanks in advanced.
